2-D Real-analytic function (power series) bounded above and below by a polynomial
Let $B_{\delta}\in \Bbb{R}^2$ be a closed ball of radius $\delta < 1$ be centered at $(0,0)$. Let $f:B_{\delta} \to \Bbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ be real-analytic. Moreover assume that the only zero of $f(x,y)$ is at $(0,0)$.
$\textbf{Claim.}$ There exists polynomials $p_1(x,y), p_2(x,y)$ and $0<\delta' \leq \delta$ such that
$$
0\leq p_1(x,y) \leq f(x,y) \leq p_2(x,y)
$$
for all $(x,y) \in B_{\delta'}$. Moreover, the only zero of $p_1(x,y), p_2(x,y)$ for $(x,y)\in B_{\delta'}$ is $(0,0)$.
$\textbf{Ideas.}$ The statement is clearly true if $f(x,y)$ is a polynomial. I would like to show that it also holds for real-analytic functions that are defined only in terms of their power series (Taylor series). My first idea was trying to utilize Stone-Weierstrass; however, this will not ensure the positivity constraint on $p_1(x,y)$. Moreover, it won't give a uniform lower bound. Any other direction/counter-example would be appreciated.
I've asked a similar question: Upper/Lower bounds of real-analytic functions with infinite Taylor series. However, I wasn't as precise as I should have been. Moreover, I've looked at How to bound the remainder of a truncated power series?. But, my function is not analytic, it is only real-analytic. Moreover, even if I can obtain a lower bound on the Remainder, I don't think it would ensure the positivity constraint on $p_1(x,y)$.

Sorry, I realized that my idea was complete nonesense. The lower bound is actually fairly difficult.

For this answer we will look directly at $f:\mathbb{R}^n \supset B_\delta \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ real-analytic and $x=(x_1, \dots, x_n)$.
Lower bound: The lower bound is fairly hard and is known as the Lojasiewicz inequality. It says the following:
Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ open, $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ real-analytic and $Z=f^{-1}(\{0\})$ the zero locus of $f$. For any compact set $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ there exists $\alpha \geq 2$ and $C>0$ such that
$$ \inf_{z\in Z} \vert x-z\vert^\alpha \leq  C \vert f(x)\vert $$
for all $x\in K$.
In our case this tells us (as $Z=\{(0,\dots, 0)\}$) that there exist constants $c,\alpha>0$ such that for all $x\in \overline{B((0,\dots, 0), \delta')}$
$$ c\vert x \vert^{\alpha} \leq \vert f(x)\vert = f(x). $$
Now replace $\alpha$ by $\beta=2\lceil \alpha\rceil$ (which is an even natural number) and $\vert x \vert^\beta$ is a polynomial in $x_1, \dots, x_n$.
Upper bound: As $f$ has only a single zero, we get that $\partial_j f(0, \dots, 0) = 0$ for all $j\in \{1, \dots, n\}$ (otherwise we could use the implicit function theorem to show that $f$ has more than one zero). Thus, by Taylor's theorem we get
$$  f(x)  = \sum_{\alpha\in \mathbb{N}_0^n \ : \ \vert \alpha \vert =2} \frac{\partial^\alpha f(0,\dots,0)}{\alpha!}  x^\alpha + o(\vert x \vert^2).$$
Hence, we get
$$ f(x) = \vert f(x) \vert \leq \left( \sum_{\alpha\in \mathbb{N}_0^n \ : \ \vert \alpha \vert =2} \frac{\vert\partial^\alpha f(0,\dots,0) \vert}{\alpha!} \right) \vert x \vert^2 + o(\vert x \vert^2).$$
As we are working on ball we can find a suitable constant to show that
$$ f(x) \leq C \vert x \vert^2. $$
Note that for this to work, we can replace real-analytic by $C^3$.

Thanks! I already knew of Lojaseiwicz's inequality and was trying to see if I could find an elementary proof. If just feels slightly out of place whenever your manuscript is mainly analysis and you have to use some Analytic Geometry theorem.

I completely agree. Unfortunately, I do not know a simpler way than this. In the past I had a similar problem and I could not get around to use this real algebraic geometry sledge hammer :( Should you find something more elementary I'd be happy to learn about it!

@Doofenshmert Actually, in this case it is not so clear to me how an easier proof would look like. It cannot solely rely on the Taylor polynomial (this would mean that it would hold for $C^\infty$ functions too and this is not the case as $e^{-1/x^2}$ shows). Thus, it must be something that distinguishes real-analytic function from smooth ones.

My current idea is that maybe the "minimal curve" of the real analytic function is also real analytic. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4921577/minimums-of-2-d-function-form-a-continuous-function-itself. From there you can then bound below said 1D function. However, I've spent too much time trying to find an elementary proof.

@Doofenshmert Another possible attack would be to symmetrize the function (to get some radial function). Though then you would need to be able to show that the minima of the symmetrized function and the original function are comparable.

I've also had that idea, but don't know how to even begin trying to symmetrize said function. Also the symmetrized function would also have to bound the original function below or as you said the minima would have to be agree/be comparable.

I would define $$ g(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(\cos(\theta)x-\sin(\theta)y, \sin(\theta)x+\cos(\theta)y) d\theta. $$ This is again real-analytic (and radially symmetric). However, as you wrote, the tough part is to show that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ we have $$ f(x,y)\geq C g(x,y). $$
