Minimums of 2-D function form a continuous function itself.
Let $B_{\delta}\subseteq \Bbb{R}^2$ be a closed ball of radius $\delta < 1$ centered at $(0,0)$. Let $f:B_{\delta}\to \Bbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ be real-analytic and have only one zero in $B_{\delta}$, namely, $(0,0)$. Let $\tilde{f}(r,\theta)$ be the polar coordinate representation of $f$. Let
$$
M(r) = \min_{\theta\in[0,2\pi)}\tilde{f}(r,\theta).
$$
Then, $M(r)$ is continuous for $r \leq \delta$. (It would be even cooler if $M(r)$ were also real-analytic.)
$\textbf{Ideas.}$ I'm at a loss. I'm somewhat tried thinking about the $\epsilon, \delta$ version of continuity, but it is non-trivial whenever you are dealing with polar coordinates. Any advice would be appreciate, or a counter-example.
This is question/claim is interesting because it could give us a way to prove a specific case of Lojaseiwicz's Inequality using elementary (analysis) methods in 2 dimensions.

Hin t: $\tilde{f}(r,\theta)$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\delta]\times [0,2\pi]$.

If the polar coordinates are troubling you, note that $\tilde f(r,\theta) = f(r\cos \theta , r\sin \theta)$.
